# Not getting response while reading data from smart card using JavaCard and APDU

Tags: applet, byte, smartcard, javacard, apdu

I studied all API and specification of java card 
and I write a code for read data from smart card.
But I don't know where it return response.

The code I have written is given below.

```
private void readData(APDU apdu) throws ISOException
{
     byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
     short in_len1=apdu.setIncomingAndReceive();
     apdu.receiveBytes(ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA);
}
```

- smart card type = contact card
- using java card 2.2.2 with using apdu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to implement the process method (similar to the main method of a c program). see also http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javacard/javacard2-138597.html

Comment: thank you for your response.Above code is wrong for read data from smart card.